# Xamarin object.variable.count() not working

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So, I deserialized a JSON response into a .NET object.

The object comes back. Foo {FooApp.RootObject}. I expand Foo to see results populated with 20 results. results Count = 20.

The problem is when I try.

Foo.results.Count() my app blows a gasket. it says Foo.results:Unknown member: results.

However, when I expand Foo I see results Count = 20 and I can even dive into to the objects.

```
 var Foo = await FooAPI.FindFoo(API);
 Random rnd = new Random();
 var count = Foo.results.Count(); // fails here.
 int r = rnd.Next(count);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

```
        public static async Task<dynamic> FindFoo(string API)
    {
        HttpClient getPlaces = new HttpClient();
        var response = await getPlaces.GetAsync(API);
        dynamic data = null;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseContent);
        }
        return data;
    }
```

Comment: What `FindFoo` returns? Post this function, too.

Answer (score 0):

May be its helpful for you issue , dont know still try this once

If your deserialize the json object then you can cast it to data table whenever deserialize , so that you will get number of records in your table.

```
DataTable dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(Result.ToString());
```

here, Result means your json response.